# Juliaにおいてdeleterows!が機能しない

Tags: julia

Juliaのにおいて、以下のようにDataFrameを使用して、3行のデータフレームを作成しました。

```
df = DataFrame(A = Int[], B = String[])
push!(df, (1, "Apple"))
push!(df, (2, "Banana"))
push!(df, (3, "Cherry"))
```

そしてその直後で3行目を削除しようと以下のように記述したところ、

```
deleterows!(df, 3)
```

以下のようなエラー分が返ってきてしまいました。

```
UndefVarError: deleterows! not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[239]:1
 [2] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1094
```

公式ドキュメントなどを参照しても何がエラーの原因となっち得るのかわからず困っております。
どなたかお力添えいただけると大変助かります。

Comment: 名前が変更された様です。[Rename deleterows! to delete! (#2189) · JuliaData/DataFrames.jl@eb6fc52](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/commit/eb6fc526957cd17d78ffdf80e59aff1cb7102569)

Comment: ありがとうございます！ 無事作動しました。